# How to add a CSS style dynamically to HEAD tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unusual scenario, where I need to take content for a `STYLE` tag (only the **second tag**) from `HTML document A` and add it to the `HEAD` tag after the `LINK` tag of `HTML DOCUMENT B`. A and B are on the same server.
It must be dynamically, I have no control of the CSS generated (cms).

I would like to know:

- What is the best approach, I need to avoid page flickering
- What is the less expensive

I can use HTML5 and JQUERY. I target mainly web-kit.

```
    HTML A

    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
                .styleA {}
    </style>
<!-- I am interested just in the following style tag
    <style type="text/css">
                .styleB {}
    </style>
//>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>



    HTML B

    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="someothercss.css">
    <!-- should be injected here -->
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an IFrame with each page getting its own CSS?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately I cannot use IFrames

Comment: How can you have multiple HTML/Body tags in the same page?

Comment: Do you have full control over the HTML and CSS?

Comment: Why can't you just place common piece of CSS to a separate file and then `<link>` it to both pages?

Comment: Unfortunately the CSS is generated by CMS and I have limited control.

Comment: Interesting approach http://www.roypeled.com/injecting-dynamic-css-with-chromes-content-script-before-the-page-loads/

Comment: So, what's the nature of HTML files? Generated by CMS, static page or CMS template parts? If it is template, then there should be **layout** part with common styles etc. and **actual content** part.

Comment: Still trying to understand your requirements. You want to copy the second style element from page A into page B at runtime using JS?

Comment: It is possible to manipulate `<style>` tags with js, of coarse, but this is bad, bad design. What CMS are you using? Try to see, how you can reorganize your website assets in it. In general, CMS should not generate CSS, but if it is necessary - it should be done by special **controller/action** i.e. URI

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate .js file with jQuery that manipulate the css (or just add it in the HTML code itself) and then just link the .js to HTML B or both if you want. Just set all the elements that needs to inherit the style to a class and then write the jQuery to manipulate the css for that class.

Example code:

```
    $(".className").css({"background-color":"black","font-size":"12px"});
```

You can add and manipulate any css style within the curly brackets.

Comment: @GibboK if you want to make it more dynamic you can create a JavaScript function with the jQuery that manipulates the css and then call it on the HTML elements DOM events like onClick, onMouseover etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below ways:

1. You can add that particular CSS Style in each page.
2. Have that particular CSS style in a separate Stylesheet. and refer that style
   sheet in the pages where needed.